# Memory leak and local variables

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, delegates

I have the following method (in a RegionAdapter for prism).

```
protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, DocumentPane regionTarget)
{
    region.Views.CollectionChanged += delegate(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnViewsCollectionChanged(sender, e, region, regionTarget);
    };
}
```

My problem is that by subscribing to the event this way, I have a memory leak. But the region and regionTarget parameters are local variables for Adapt.

I tried looking this up to see if someone handled the scenario differently, but MSDN and MVPs all use this leaky approach...

How should I handle it so that I can unsubscribe the event later on?

**EDIT:**
The code above is just an example that I think clearly illustrates the problem.
The actual code that leaks memory is as follows:

```
private void OnViewsCollectionChanged(object sender, 
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, IRegion region, 
    DocumentPane regionTarget)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        //Add content panes for each associated view.
        foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
        {
            UIElement view = item as UIElement;

            if (view != null)
            {
                DockableContent newContentPane = new DockableContent();
                newContentPane.IsCloseable = true;
                newContentPane.HideOnClose = false;

                ScrollViewer sViewer = new ScrollViewer()
                {
                    Content = item,
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
                };
                newContentPane.Content = sViewer;

                //When contentPane is closed remove the associated region
                // (MEMORY LEAK)
                newContentPane.Closed += (contentPaneSender, args) =>
                {
                    DockableContent docker =
                        contentPaneSender as DockableContent;
                    ScrollViewer scroller = docker.Content as ScrollViewer;
                    region.Remove(scroller.Content);
                    IDisposable dispView = scroller.Content as IDisposable;
                    if (dispView != null) dispView.Dispose();
                    scroller.Content = null;
                };
                regionTarget.Items.Add(newContentPane);
                newContentPane.Activate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Bab.

Comment: Why do you think it leaks memory? The instance of the class that contains the `Adapt` method stays in memory as long as the `Views` instance stays referenced. When the `region` will get collected, so will your `Adapter`. Is your `region` a reference to a static instance?

Comment: If you make the `OnViewsCollectionChanged` method static (if possible), it prevents the `Adapter` from being referenced.

Comment: Actually, this is the tiniest bit to reproduce the problem. The region most used is injected with an unlimited amount of Views. I'll update the question to show what cause the bad memory leak, but I guess you understand that not unsubscribing = memory leak.

Comment: @Steven So if I got that right, If i put the content of the anonymous method used in the Closed event handling, in a regular static method, I ensure there will be no memory leaks?

Comment: That's right. The C# compiler will generate an anonymous type with `region` and `regionTarget` as public fields on it, and when `OnViewsCollectionChanged` is an instance method, that anonymous type will also contain a reference to the instance holding `OnViewsCollectionChanged`. When `OnViewsCollectionChanged` is static, that anonymous type will not contain a reference to that instance, and that instance will therefore not be kept alive. You can confirm this using Reflector.

Comment: @Steven can you put it as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Use concrete method instead of anonym. For ex:

```
   private Region _region;
   DocumentPane _regionTarget
   protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, DocumentPane regionTarget)
    {
        _region = region;
        _regionTarget = regionTarget;
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        OnViewsCollectionChanged(sender, e, _region, _regionTarget);
    }

    ...
    private void Unsubscribe() 
    {
      _region.Views.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will not compile: region and regionTarget are unknown variables for the OnCollectionChanged method. They are local to Adapt.

Comment: I thought about that, but now those 2 variables are no longer local, they're global. I'm sure there has to be another way maybe using a trick with delegates i don't know about... Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Removing the anonymous method doesn't change anything. The instance will still be referenced. Unsubstribing on the other hand, does do the trick.

Comment: Yes but how could I do it without moving the variables outside the method?